# Backing bind com componentes JSF

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2

Sou iniciante em Java EE e estou utilizando um e-book da Algaworks "Java EE 7, com JSF, PrimeFaces e CDI. Até o `ManagedBean` ocorreu normalmente, mas quando iniciei com o backing bean o Java não conseguiu encontrar a propriedade com `HtmlInputText`. Conforme o Exemplo do e-book alterei a classe `NomeBean` como segue:

**NomesBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NomesBean {
    private String nome;
    private List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();
    private HtmlInputText inputNome;
    private HtmlCommandButton botaoAdicionar;

    public void adicionar() {
        this.nomes.add(nome);
        // desativa campo e botão quando mais que 3 nomes
        // forem adicionados
        if (this.nomes.size() > 3) {
        this.inputNome.setDisabled(true);
        this.botaoAdicionar.setDisabled(true);
        this.botaoAdicionar.setValue("Muitos nomes adicionados...");
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<String> getNomes() {
        return nomes;
    }

}
```

**nomes.xhtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/199/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
    <title>Lista Nomes</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            Nome: <h:inputText value="#{nomesBean.nome}" binding="#{nomesBean.inputNome}" />
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" action="#{nomesBean.adicionar}" binding="#{nomesBean.botaoAdicionar}" />
            <ol>
                <ui:repeat var="nome" value="#{nomesBean.nomes}">
                    <li>#{nome}</li>
                </ui:repeat>
            </ol>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

**Saída de erro:**

```
    HTTP Status 500 - /nomes.xhtml @10,85 binding="#{nomesBean.inputNome}": Property 'inputNome' not found on type com.algaworks.financeiro.model.NomesBean

    type Exception report

    message /nomes.xhtml @10,85 binding="#{nomesBean.inputNome}": Property 'inputNome' not found on type com.algaworks.financeiro.model.NomesBean

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: /nomes.xhtml @10,85 binding="#{nomesBean.inputNome}": Property 'inputNome' not found on type com.algaworks.financeiro.model.NomesBean
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    root cause

    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /nomes.xhtml @10,85 binding="#{nomesBean.inputNome}": Property 'inputNome' not found on type com.algaworks.financeiro.model.NomesBean
        com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
        com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1943)
        com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1149)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:596)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:175)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
        com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:991)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    root cause

    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'inputNome' not found on type com.algaworks.financeiro.model.NomesBean
        javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
        javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
        javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
        javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
        com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
        org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1943)
        com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1149)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:596)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:175)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
        com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:991)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.20 logs.

    Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
```

Mas há mais de três horas com buscar no Google não consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: a construção dessa sua classe está certa?
me parece que esse NomeBean seria apenas sua classe com as propriedades e você teria uma outra classe por exemplo `NomesLogica`onde acessaria as propriedades da `NomeBean` @adrianosymphony

Comment: cade os getters e setters do componente do html unput text?@adrianosymphony

Answer (score 1):

**adrianosymphony**, vou editar minha resposta conforme sua edição na pergunta

Adicione os `getters` e `setters` para **inputNome** e **botaoAdicionar**;

Comment: Mesmo com essas alterações continuou sem acesso a propriedade

Comment: posta como esta seus getters e setters

Comment: @adrianosymphony, nada?

Comment: Tive o mesmo erro e quando segui a dica do colega acima,adicionei os getters e setters o Problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

A informação de criar os getters e setters funcionou. O final da class NomesBean ficou assim:

```
public HtmlInputText getInputNome() {
    return inputNome;
}

public void setInputNome(HtmlInputText inputNome) {
    this.inputNome = inputNome;
}

public HtmlCommandButton getBotaoAdicionar() {
    return botaoAdicionar;
}

public void setBotaoAdicionar(HtmlCommandButton botaoAdicionar) {
    this.botaoAdicionar = botaoAdicionar;
}
```